# Angular 1.2 ng-enter-stagger animation not working

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have been using http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/12/staggering-animations-in-angularjs.html as my reference guide for implementing .ng-enter-stagger for my animations, but it isn't working for me. I have tried re-ordering my code, not using SASS, etc. All the resources I have found indicate that I should use this as a guide (it's only about 4 lines of actual CSS to implement) :

```
 .repeat-animation.ng-enter-stagger,
 .repeat-animation.ng-leave-stagger,
 .repeat-animation.ng-move-stagger {
   /* notice how we're using animation instead of transition here */ 
   -webkit-animation-delay:0.2s;
   animation-delay:0.2s;

   /* yes we still need to do this too */
   -webkit-animation-duration:0;
   animation-duration:0;
}
```

Below is my CSS and related ng-repeat I am trying to perform the animation. What is going wrong with this code?

View:

```
 <div class="gray-section repeat-animation" ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.filteredCustomers | paginate:ctrl.paginator">
```

SASS:

```
    .repeat-animation {

        &.ng-enter-stagger {
            transition-delay: 1s;
            -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
            -o-transition-delay: 1s;
            -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;

            transition-duration: 0 !important;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0 !important;
            -o-transition-duration: 0 !important;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0 !important;
        }

        &.ng-enter {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
            -moz-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
            -o-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
            transform: translate(0px, 100px);
            opacity: 0;
        }

        &.ng-leave {
            &.ng-leave-active {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
```

global-app.js:

```
        apps.Global = angular.module('Global', [
            'ngAnimate',
          apps.CustomersPage.module.name,
          lfl.paginator.module.name
        ]);

        angular.bootstrap(document.body, [apps.Global.name]);
```